How are cascading router-view elements handled?
TL;DR: how are the priorities of Vue routes (global vs child) calculated?
Quasar is a Vue framework that can bootstrap applications. I am trying to follow its suggested structure but I am not sure how Vue routing works with cascading router-view elements.
In a bootstrapped application, the routes are defined as
import type { RouteRecordRaw } from 'vue-router';

const routes: RouteRecordRaw[] = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: () => import('layouts/MainLayout.vue'),
    children: [{ path: '', component: () => import('pages/IndexPage.vue') }],
  },

  // Always leave this as last one,
  // but you can also remove it
  {
    path: '/:catchAll(.*)*',
    component: () => import('pages/ErrorNotFound.vue'),
  },
];

export default routes;

Let's assume that we are at /.
The first component that starts everything else (App.vue) is
<template>
  <router-view />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
//
</script>

So when I am at /, the MainLayout component is lazy loaded. This is it, I removed all other components (sidebar etc.) to just keep the part that is relevant to this question:
<template>
  <q-layout view="lHh Lpr lFf">

<!-- header, sidebar ->

    <q-page-container>
      <router-view />
    </q-page-container>
  </q-layout>
</template>

So we have again <router-view />. What is it supposed to display?
I know the answer is IndexPage.vue and I am guessing that this is because it is a child, with a '' path. Which other path entries are possible for children?
If this is, say, admin, how does <router-view /> know that it is this component that should be mounted, and not the one from this slightly expanded routes?
import type { RouteRecordRaw } from 'vue-router';

const routes: RouteRecordRaw[] = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: () => import('layouts/MainLayout.vue'),
    children: [
      { path: '', component: () => import('pages/IndexPage.vue') },
      { path: 'admin', component: () => import('pages/AdminPage.vue') },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: '/admin',
    component: () => import('layouts/AnotherAdminPage.vue'),
  },

  // Always leave this as last one,
  // but you can also remove it
  {
    path: '/:catchAll(.*)*',
    component: () => import('pages/ErrorNotFound.vue'),
  },
]

export default routes;

Which of AnotherAdminPage or AdminPage will be mounted and why?
In other words: what is the precedence when choosing routes?

Child paths use the current parent path as a starting reference.  So path: '' as a child route is active if the parent path is an exact match because the child has no path of its own, in your case /.  Child with path: 'admin' is active when the current path is {parent-path}/admin, or in your case just /admin since / is the parent path.

@yoduh ah ok, so / + the admin child would not match /admin because / does not exactly match /admin. /admin will be matched by the global /admin in that case. Would you mind turning your comment into an answer so that I can accept it? Thanks!

/ + the admin child does match /admin.  The fact it's a combination of paths does not matter.  It's still an exact match, and vue-router finds it first (reading top to bottom), and will never hit the other "global" /admin in normal cases. The only real way you could get to "AnotherAdminPage" would be programmatic navigation using a route's name property to differentiate between them (which you would need to add).  Navigation guard might also be needed depending on when exactly you need to determine redirection.

Another option would be to give the second admin page a different unique path.

@yoduh "Another option would be to give the second admin page a different unique path" → the example I gave is on purpose contrived to hit the specific case I wanted to understand. In my real application there will be no collisions but I did not now how the final route is calculated (chosen)
